# Flask and Vue not connecting on raspberry pi zero

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to have a simple back-end and front-end running on my raspberry pi and it is not working.

When I run the code on my laptop, it works fine and front-end could communicate with flask, even without cors. But when I try to run it on the raspberry pi, it does not even come with an error message.

The first time I ran both ends on the rpi, vue gave an error with no connection to server, but the times after, it ran without error messages, just does not work

Python Flask application:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import time
import os

deployedRasp = False

if os.uname()[0] == 'Linux':
    deployedRasp = True
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    pins = [11, 13, 31, 37] # desklamp, chain light, ceiling light on/off
    GPIO.setup(pins, GPIO.OUT)

# Time between min and max = 4 seconds
DIMM_VALUE = 50

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return "use vue front-end to access endpoints", 200

@app.route('/relay', methods=['GET'])
def relay_handler():
    state = request.args.get('state', type=str)
    lamp = request.args.get('light_source', type=str)
    light_state = {'On': 1, 'Off': 0}
    light_pin = {'desk': 11, 'chain': 13}
    if deployedRasp:
        GPIO.output(light_pin[lamp], light_state[state])
    return jsonify(result='Turned {lamp} {state}'), 200

@app.route('/ikea_lights', methods=['GET'])
def ikea_lights_handler():
    state = request.args.get('state', type=str)
    dimmValue = request.args.get('value', type=str)
    if state != None:
        a = Lights(state)
        result = 'Turned {} : {}'.format(state, a)
        print(result)
        return result, 200
    if dimmValue != None:
        dimm(int(dimmValue))
        result = 'Dimmed {}'.format(dimmValue)
        print(result)
        return result, 200
    return "missing parametre", 400

@app.route('/disco', methods=['GET'])
def disco():
    for x in range(10):
        GPIO.output(11, 0)
        time.sleep(0.02)
        GPIO.output(11,1)
        time.sleep(0.02)

def dimm(dimm_value):
    global DIMM_VALUE
    if dimm_value < DIMM_VALUE:
        dimm = 4.5 / (100 / (DIMM_VALUE - dimm_value))
        Lights(state='Off', delay=dimm)
        DIMM_VALUE = dimm_value

    elif dimm_value > DIMM_VALUE and not dimm_value == 100:
        dimm = 4.5 / (100 / (dimm_value - DIMM_VALUE))
        Lights(state='On', delay=dimm)
        DIMM_VALUE = dimm_value

    elif dimm_value == 100:
        Lights(state='On', delay=4)
        DIMM_VALUE = 100

def Lights(state, delay=0.1): # Default delay represents a click on the button
    light_pin = {'On': 37, 'Off': 31}
    if deployedRasp:
        GPIO.output(light_pin[state], 1)
        time.sleep(delay)
        GPIO.output(light_pin[state], 0)
        return False
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if deployedRasp:
        GPIO.output(11, 1)
        GPIO.output(13, 1)
    Lights(state='Off', delay=4)
    Lights(state='On', delay=2)
    app.run(debug=True, port=3000, host='0.0.0.0')
```

And the vue view:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
      <p>Loftslamper</p>
      <button type = "button" v-on:click="ikea_lights('On')">Tænd</button>
      <button type = "button" v-on:click="ikea_lights('Off')">Sluk</button><br>
      <p>Dæmpning</p>
      <button type = "button" v-on:click="ikea_lights(25)">25</button>
      <button type = "button" v-on:click="ikea_lights(50)">50</button>
      <button type = "button" v-on:click="ikea_lights(75)">75</button>
      <button type = "button" v-on:click="ikea_lights(100)">100</button><br>
      <p>Skrivebords lampe</p>
      <button type = "button" v-on:click="relay('desk', 'On')">Tænd</button>
      <button type = "button" v-on:click="relay('desk', 'Off')">Sluk</button><br>
      <p>Lys kæde</p>
      <button type = "button" v-on:click="relay('chain', 'On')">Tænd</button>
      <button type = "button" v-on:click="relay('chain', 'Off')">Sluk</button><br>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  methods : {
    ikea_lights : function(value){
      if(typeof(value) == "string"){
        this.fetchAPICall("ikea_lights?state=" + value, "GET");
      }
      else if(typeof(value) == "number"){
        this.fetchAPICall("ikea_lights?value=" + value, "GET");
      }
    },
    relay : function (dest, state){ 
      this.fetchAPICall("relay?state=" + String(state) + "&light_source=" + String(dest), "GET")
    },
    fetchAPICall : async function (route, method) {
      let url = "http://localhost:3000/" + route
      console.log(url);
      try {
        return await fetch(url, { method: method });
      } 
      catch (err) {
        alert("Error: " + err);
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Also I'm a newcomer so if you have any tips regarding my code, please help me. Thanks.

Edit: When I tested with cors, I added `cross_origin()` with every route.

Edit2: When I simply just use `curl "{Raspberry Pi IP}:3000/ikea_lights?state=Off"` it works, but won't work without the quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found the reason or a perfect fix, but realized npm was using 100% of my Zero's cpu, so switched it out with a Raspberry Pi 3B and did a fresh install of everything with a newer version of node and now it works